# stat on an encrypted volume in osx takes a long time

Tags: linux, osx, encryption, stat

My workstation is a MacBook Pro with an SSD.  For security reasons, my main volume is encrypted.
I ran this command on a folder:

```
time find . -exec stat {} + >/dev/null

real    0m5.205s
user    0m0.367s
sys     0m4.556s
```

The folder contains 1961 items.  Running the same command on a linux (debian) machine without ssd takes .09s real (similar folder, except it contains 1150 items).

Also, running `find . -ls | wc -l` on my workstation only takes .05s real (it also lists modification dates).

Is there anything that I can do to speed things up?

For the record, I did this timing because my boost.build project takes 6s to check the dependencies on my workstation, while it takes less than a second on the linux machine.

Edit:
I copied the folder in question to another laptop with a 7200rpm non-encrypted hard disk, the find stat command takes 2.445s system time.

Edit 2:
I decrypted my hard disk, and now it takes ~3.6s on the same ssd on osx.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have TRIM enabled for your SSD in OS X. I use http://www.groths.org/trim-enabler/ and I noticed a considerable speed increase after installing it and rebooting with support enabled.

Try that and post back if that helps your I/O speeds.

Also, is it encrypted on the Linux machine? Encryption will provide some overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the TRIM tip, I have enabled it now.  But timings don't seem to have improved: 4.2s real, and 3.8s system are the minimum timings.  I have copied the folder to a new location, in an attempt to let the trim-change have its effect (?).  Timings are the same as in the old location.

Comment: Ultimately stat() is a system call and since it gathers information from an inode it's entirely dependent on disk I/O. Unless the Linux disk is not encrypted I am not entirely sure what would cause that much slowdown unless it's just the native Darwin taking its time. 3.8 vs .09 _could_ be that the disk is encrypted only on OS X.